# Javascript: Transforming a string

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

```
var myString = 'param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3';
```

and want to transform it into this:

```
var new = {
    'param1': 'value1', 
    'param2': 'value2', 
    'param3': 'value3'
}
```

What is the shortest way to do it? Thanks

Comment: tymeJV answer is correct, but why not using standard JSON parsing/stringifying?
`var myString = "{\"param1\"=\"value1\",\"param2\"=\"value2\",\"param3\"=\"value3\"}"`
in that case you could use `var myObj = JSON.parse(myString);`.

There are libraries in all common programming languages for operating with JSON if that is your concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can do:

```
var parts = "param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3".split("&");
var myObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    var pairs = parts[1].split("=");
    myObj[pairs[0]] = pairs[1];
}
```

Comment: You may want to use decodeURIComponent